# Open a new database and close the old one

Tags: vba, ms-access

Greetings all:  I have been struggling for 2 days to figure this out and have tried various techniques with frustrating results.  I'm trying to start up a different database and close/quit the calling (first) database. I've created 2 button-click subs, one works very well and the second (which appears to be identical) flashes the new Db and then immediately returns to the calling DB.  Here's the code that works well:

```
Dim objLeaveLookup As Object
Dim objOtherMenu As Object

Set objOtherMenu = GetObject("M:\QueryData\DBA Maintenance.mdb")
Set objLeaveLookup = GetObject("M:\QueryData\DBA_LookUp.mdb")

'   Open Maintenance menu & quit DBA_Lookup
objOtherMenu.DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_MaintMenu"
objLeaveLookup.Application.Quit
```

and here is the code flashes the different Db, then frustratingly immediately returns to the original Db:

```
Dim objLeaveLookup As Object

Set objOtherMenu = GetObject("M:\QueryData\PurchMenu.mdb", "Access.Application").Application
Set objLeaveLookup = GetObject("M:\QueryData\DBA_LookUp.mdb", "Access.Application").Application

'   Open Purchasing menu & quit DBA_LookUp
objOtherMenu.DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_PurMenu"
objLeaveLookup.Application.Quit
```

Any help to get the desired results will be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may use FollowHyperlink.

See here: https://www.devhut.net/2018/01/21/ms-access-vba-open-another-database/

Comment: The suggested solution does the first part (opening another database) well.  But I also need to close/quit the first 'calling' database.  How's that done?

Comment: for closing the current database you just use 'Application.Quit'

Comment: Thanks @Klaus.  To state my problem more precisely, I have just opened a new instance of Access and and now want to close the OLD instance, not the current one.